How to link web subscribers to web on iOS and use External link account entitlement only for a share of users
I have a substantial number of users who are subscribed through the web and launching an upgrade experience. I'd like to be able to link these users out to the web version. I know External Link Account Entitlement is only available for reader apps but curious if anyone has come up with ideas to have only web subscribers be able to land on the web without risking Apple approval. I don't want to get rid of IAP, just be able to have users who originally subscribed elsewhere be able to upgrade. IAP subscribers can continue to do so.
